# turn list to dictionary where single key stores values which save index of repeated element

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I want to turn a list with repeated string like

```
["ask","a","public","question","ask","a","public","question"]
```

And the output dictionary should has element of list as key and the occurrence indexes as values.

```
{"ask":[0,4],"a":[1,5],"public":[2,6],"question";[3,7]}
```

Any hint?
I actually dealing with a bigram perplexity of a corpus, where I have already get the total occurrence of bigram words, i.e., count(B|A), but now I need to get the total occurrence of count(A), where count(A), should be all occurrences of any two words combination start from A. I took the bigram dictionary keys as list and change it to contains only the first words list such as

```
[['You', 'will'], ['will', 'face'], ['face', 'many'], ['many', 'defeats']
```

to

```
['You', 'will', 'face', 'many']
```

, So I need to calculate all occurrences of each words one by one in that bigram dictionary. I tried several data structures like list, dict, and defaultdict, but they all took so long. I just want to find another datastructure that can deal fastly

Answer (score -2, accepted):

There are various ways to do this.

This one uses [**`defaultdict`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict).

```
from collections import defaultdict
result = defaultdict(list)

mylst = ["ask", "a", "public", "question", "ask", "a", "public", "question"]

for index, item in enumerate(mylst):
    result[item].append(index)

print(dict(result))
```

Another way is to use `dict` [**`setdefault`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault) method.

```
result = {}
mylst = ["ask", "a", "public", "question", "ask", "a", "public", "question"]

for index, item in enumerate(mylst):
    result.setdefault(item, []).append(index)

print(result)
```

---

Another one would be to use try-except with a dictionary.